# Mysql - How to replace 0s in my columns with a hyphen

Tags: mysql

When I run a query I would like to replace all the 0s that generate in my columns with a hyphen, "-".

What is the easiest function  or statement to make this change? The columns are not null, and the 0s are therefore generated when to data applies.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
SELECT IF(column, column, '-')
```

If `column` evaluates to true, it will return the value in `column`, otherwise, the '-' as specified.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MySQL [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)

```
 SELECT REPLACE(field_name,'0','-');
```

Comment: what if i have 0 defined as int datatype, what can i do for that?